# Best way to add Hex values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hex value (0x0020004E0000 ... which is the base address to a hardware address). I need to add 0x04 to the base for each register. I have been doing this by first converting the base address to a base 10 number, then adding 4 to that value. The sum I then take and convert back to hex all via the string class .to_s and .to_i.

Is there a better way to do this so I'm not converting back-and-forth between base 10 and base 16 all the time? (FYI, in my previous AppleScript script, I punted hex math to the OS and let bc take care of the addition for me).

Comment: Why are you converting it back and forth? Keep it as a number and only do the final conversion to a hexadecimal string when you need to. (If you need to do this every time, then there is no better way.)

Comment: I'm picking it up as a string, never realized I could leave it as 0x... and have Ruby understand it was hex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0x0020004E0000 + 0x04`

or simply

`0x0020004E0000 + 4`

Comment: this seems to work by internally converting the hex number to a decimal. I don't think I was clear enough... I still need to hex value to stay as a hex (or convert it back to hex) so I can use it in a string where it would show the hex value.

Comment: @WayneBrissette: "Internally converting the number to decimal" makes no sense.  You're missing the point and confusing representation with value.  4 is 4 no matter how you say it.

Comment: `"0x" + (0x0020004E0000 + 4).to_s(16).upcase`

Comment: Ed, you're absolutely correct. What I was missing was that Ruby is doing stuff for me that I missed. Thanks for pointing that out! I knew I should have used irb to mess around more.

Comment: @MatthewRatzloff I'd go for `"0x%X" % (0x0020004E0000 + 4)` instead.

Comment: In practice I use % or string interpolation, but I thought I would try to avoid clouding the issue. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have four ways of representing integer values in Ruby

```
64        # integer
0x40      # hexadecimal
0100      # octal
0b1000000 # binary

# These are all 64.
```

Answer (score 0):

A number is a number is a number, no matter how it is represented internally or displayed to the user.  Just add them as you would any other number.  If you want to *view* them as Hex later then fine; format them for output.

You are confusing representation with value.  Ruby can parse a number represented in Hex just as well as it can parse a decimal, binary, or octal value.

`0x04 (Hex) == 4 (decimal) == 100 (binary)`

All the same thing.